# Why does mySQL automatically add display length to numeric values when adding zerofill property

Tags: mysql, datatypes

I am trying to understand better how the data types are processed by the MySQL system, so I created a table in the following way:

```
# Field, Type, Null, Key, Default, Extra
test1, tinyint(3) unsigned zerofill, YES, , , 
test2, smallint(5) unsigned zerofill, YES, , , 
test3, int(10) unsigned zerofill, YES, , , 
test4, bigint(20) unsigned zerofill, YES, , ,
```

I initially added only the columns without autofill:

```
create table test (
test1 tinyint,
test2 smallint,
test3 int,
test4 bigint
);
```

And the table looked like this:

```
# Field Type    Null    Key Default Extra
test1   tinyint  YES            
test2   smallint    YES         
test3   int YES         
test4   bigint  YES
```

But then I added the autofill property via alter table and the final result was this:

```
# Field Type    Null    Key Default Extra
test1   tinyint(3) unsigned zerofill    YES         
test2   smallint(5) unsigned zerofill   YES         
test3   int(10) unsigned zerofill   YES         
test4   bigint(20) unsigned zerofill    YES
```

My question is why does it define automatically the display length for the columns?

Comment: mysql has fixed sizes for ints in mysql 8, so the fize behind thedatatypes is obsolete

Comment: I know it has fixed sizes. It is not a matter of wether I should put the display length or not but about why does MySQL ads it automatically when adding the zerofill property.

Comment: see if this helps you https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/numeric-type-attributes.html it explains what happens with zeorfill

Comment: When you specify ZEROFILL server must know how many zeros must be added, what final length must be obtained. If you do not specify this length then server adds it, using max possible for the datatype.

Comment: Thank you Akina. This is a really relevant answer. But I still don't understand why two zeros for tinyint and not more. From what I know tinyint is stored in one byte. Is 001 stored in one byte?

Comment: Oh I got it. It is because in a tinyint I can store maximum three characters. Thank you @Akina that was really useful.

Answer (score 0):

In the past, `INT(5)` was identical to `INT`.  The number was useful only when `ZEROFILL` was also specified.

In the future, `ZEROFILL` and the number will go away.  This incompatible change is predicted for some time in 8.0.xx.  You are probably seeing some step toward it.

Zerofill is extremely rarely used.  US Zipcodes stored in `MEDIUMINT(5) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL` is the only case I can think of off-hand.

When Zerofill goes away, there are workarounds for the rare cases where you really need it.

The number confuses a lot of people.  It takes time for newbies to understand that it is normally of no use.

Although `DESCRIBE` and `information_schema.TABLES` are tempting for displaying the schema for a table, please get in the habit of using `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; it rolls the useful information together in a canonical form.